# How to convert TypeScript Enum key to value and value to key

Tags: typescript, enums, switch-statement, typeof, keyof

**Context**
lets say I have the following enum with string values:

```
enum Fruit {
  Apple = "apple",
  Orange = "orange",
  Banana = "banana",
  Pear = "pear"
}
```

the user always inputs the literal `string` value (`"apple"`, `"banana"`, `"orange"`, `"pear"`) lets say from a drop down to eliminate possibility of invalid inputs -  which I need to convert back to type `Fruit` i.e. something like this:

```
function getFruit(fruit: string): Fruit {
    switch (fruit) {
        case "apple":
        return Fruit.Apple
        case "banana":
        return Fruit.Banana
        case "orange":
        return Fruit.Orange
        case "pear":
        return Fruit.Pear
        default:
        // I DON'T WANT THIS!
        return Fruit.Pear
    }
}
```

**Problems**

- The switch statement requires maintenance overhead
- The `getFruit()` function:

  - takes any `string` which is not represented as a union of acceptable string values (typescript will not throw a compilation error if anything other than `"apple"`, `"banana"`, `"orange"`, `"pear"` are used.) I know i can use a union of absolute strings as the `type` but thats even more overhead.
  - a `default` case needs to be provided and a default result returned.

**Question**

Is there a more elegant way to do the above? maybe with `type`/`typeof`/`keyof` or any other operations?

I ideally want to be able to:

- Eliminate the switch statement completely - (so no maintenance overhead)
- `getFruit()` function to only take `string` values that are contained in the enum programatically (without manually declaring and maintaining a union of absolute strings).

p.s. I don't care if i need to use an alternative type rather than an `enum` - its the functionality  that is important!

**Best Attempt**
the closest I've got to a solution so far is:

```
type Fruits = "apple" | "banana" | "orange" | "pear"
let Fruit = {
  Apple = "apple",
  Orange = "orange",
  Banana = "banana",
  Pear = "pear"
}
type Fruit = keyof typeof Fruit

function parseFruit(fruit: Fruits): Fruit {
  return Object.keys(Fruit).find((key) => {
    return Fruit[key as Fruit] === fruit
  }) as Fruit
}
```

this still requires for string literal union `type Fruits` and `Fruit` to be managed. This solution would be 'perfect' if I could figure out how to programmatically create the string literal union `type Fruits`.

Comment: Why do you need the keys at all?  Just use `type Fruit = "apple" | "banana" | "orange" | "pear"` and then `getFruit()` is just the identity function (`const getFruit = fruit: Fruit => fruit`) and therefore unnecessary, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZEBW).  Can you demonstrate a use case where the enum is actually helping you?

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over Enum values and find Fruit

```js
function getFruit(fruit: string): Fruit | null {
    return Object.values(Fruit).find(item => item === fruit) ?? null
}
```

Comment: `fruit: string` means any string can be passed into the function, I want to ensure its only only strings of values "apple" | "banana" | "orange" | "pear" are accepted but without having to manually list them

Comment: Just change `fruit: string` to `fruit: Fruit`?